# Are ActionScript 3 Errors used the same way Java Exceptions are ?

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3

My first guess is: NO. Exception in Java are here to catch 'expected' exceptions and handle them within the application. Error in ActionScript 3 are here to handle 'unexpected' errors.
Am I right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exceptions in ActionScript and Java have the same conception except the following:

- Java has checked and unchecked exceptions. In ActionScript all the exceptions are unchecked, so you need to read API documentation or source code to handle possible exceptions which a particular method can throw. All the ActionScript exceptions which can be thrown are inherited from the [`Error` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html).
- ActionScript in Flash Player has an asynchronous nature. This is the reason you can't handle some exceptions with a `try…catch…finally` block. Prior to Flash Player 10.1 there was no way to handle these exceptions. Flash Player 10.1 added [global error handling](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2009/10/global_error_handling_in_air_20.html) with [`flash.events.UncaughtErrorEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2).
- Some classes produce documented error events which have the same function as exceptions. They are inherited from [`flash.events.ErrorEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ErrorEvent.html) and produce exceptions in case of absence of corresponding event listeners. For example, [`SWFLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) can fire `ioError` of type `flash.events.IOErrorEvent` which should be handled.

All the other things related to errors are similar to Java :)

Comment: In Java there 3 Kinds of Exceptions
cf: [link]http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

All those cases are covered by Error class in AS3 ? I see very few use of the first kind in AS3 code. 
Example: say you have a `function getUserBy(id:int):User`, would you return null if no user or throw an AS3 Error and if so, which kind would you throw ?

Comment: @Ced If we are talking about synchronous exceptions all of them are derived from [`Error` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html) and all of them are unchecked. It doesn't depend of error kind. What about your sample code with `getUserBy(id:int):User` in case of no user for particular id there is no any strong recommendations from Adobe what you should do. So you decide: return `null` or throw an exception. The problem is that exception isn't checked. So the only way to encourage users of your class to catch them is to document them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. While Errors in Java refer to problems outside of the scope of the normal programmer, Errors in ActionScript are handled in try...catch...finally statements, like Exceptions in Java.

See this [ActionScript 2 guide](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/603/2/Exceptions-and-Exception-Handling/Page2.html) and [Adobe's documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=11_Handling_errors_04.html).

Answer (score 0):

No Its Not like that

this is the syntax

```
try {
    // statements
} catch (error:ArgumentError) {
    trace('An argument error has occured');
} catch (error:Error) {
    trace('An error has occured which is not argument related');
}
```

we can use an argumented exceptions like IO, Custom Events too.